# Do I have to chmod after ln -s?

Tags: linux, security, symbolic-link, chmod

After I create a symlink with 'ln -s' (in Ubuntu 12.04, as root), it seems to be created with 777 permissions. Is that normal? Should I always do 'chmod 644' after doing 'ln -s'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions shown for symlinks (usually `777`) are entirely irrelevant. They're fictional (*something* has to get displayed) and unchangeable. Any attempt to modify them (e.g., with `chmod`) would actually modify the permissions of the original file, not the symlink.

A symlink isn't a normal file: You can't read it, you can't write to it and you can't execute it. In a certain sense, symlinks inherit the permissions of the original file.

The only way to modify a symlink is to move (rename) or delete it, but moving or deleting a file requires permissions on the directory, not the file itself.